# Django back end and Wix front end

Tags: django, velo

I have been working on a project for a while with a developer on apps.
He was the coder and did most of the programming. I really just brought the design together and managed everything else.

He has now moved on and left me with the code. Or more to the point I have a Django database on a server. Using a postgre db with all of the data in

I have built easy websites using things like Wix and wordpress. But I am wondering is there a simple way to migrate the data to my new front end.

I can keep the digital ocean droplet or move everything to Wix. If possible just a quick way to do it.

The dB contains images, video and text.

I am not too fussed right now about making a super duper website. The layout and simplicity to build a Wix site is fine for me.

Any ideas. Is this something I can learn? Or should I just get a pro in?

Answer (score 0):

Can this book help? It's a book I wrote on API integration between Wix and Django.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09TRHSJV6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09TRHSJV6)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).